# (Why not) initialize struct val at definition

Tags: c++, c

I know this kind of initialisation is discouraged but I can't remember why, while it's working, so does anyone knows why this should be avoided :

```
typedef struct struct_test {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
} t_test;
```

thanks

Comment: Do you mean `int a: 1;` ? A bitfield? Your code doesn't compile so it is not discouraged, is just wrong (at least in C).

Comment: You're **defining** a **type**, not a **variable**.  What you are proposing is the similar to `int = 5;` where all `int` values must start as `5`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Hi tx for your answer : try it, it compile just fine on my computer.

Comment: @l_-A-_l I'm not aware of any compiler that allows this kind of constructions, not even using extensions.

Comment: @DavidRanieri, unless the OP is compiling it as C++ code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't get what you mean {int = 5;} won't compile, but this struct definition will and its member are initialiser to the right value

Comment: Try compiling it as C and not C++.  What you are doing in C++ is providing initializers for when the `struct` is created - `struct` in C++ is very similar to an object.

Comment: @r3musn0x yes, that's what I'm afraid of :). OP: C != C++

Comment: Ok tx yes I had my file with the .cpp extension so it worked with gcc and g++
Thanks for your comment !

Comment: Why do you think this is discouraged?  It's fine (in C++).

Comment: @PaulSanders Hi, ok this is want I wanted to know ! thanks I will write an answer to get this clearer : Tks !

Comment: Pick one language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's illegal in C.

In C++ it's not discouraged. Unlike initializing in the constructor, it doesn't require you to list all fields the second time (see [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself)), making it harder to forget to initialize fields.

Comment: Yeah, it's by far the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

While initializing a struct val at definition **is not allowed in C**
It's perfectly **correct in C++**

the confusion can arise when compiling a .cpp with gcc that allow this syntax in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it's correct in *modern* c++